# The absolute uri: http://www.springsource.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven

Currently, I use a 'Maven' project where I put in my pom.xml the current dependencies to use Spring Framework where org.springframework.version = 3.1.0.RELEASE :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring MVC framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

All the jar dependencies are sitting in target/myGoogleAppEngine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib. This directory contains :

```
spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
...
```

At the beginning of my address.jsp, I've the following line :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springsource.org/tags/form" %>
```

But I've the following error when I execute the address.jsp :

```
Error 500
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.springsource.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/74017-the-absolute-uri-http-www-springframework-org-tags-form-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 8):

If you open up `spring-webmvc-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar/META-INF/spring-form.tld` the `<uri>` to use is

```
<uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</uri>
```

So you should have

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Comment: In my spring-form.tld, I've this line :<uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</uri>

Answer (score 4):

Add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>Your Security Version</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't think this is the right answer, spring form is in `spring-webmvc` which according to OP is already a dependency.

Comment: They already have that library in their classpath. Also, that library is not required for the taglib they're using.

Comment: <version>Your Security Version</version> what i should give in this? its not working for me, I am trying so long please anyone suggest