# When I use modelAttribute="student",how to fix "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error"

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

[.java code and .jsp code are in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9TB.jpg)

The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

The .java code and the .jsp code can be seen in the picture.Maybe there there some mistakes arounds:    **form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student"**      in student-form.jsp    and   **theModel.addAttribute("student", theStudent);**      in StudentController.java

**error log**

```
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

03-May-2019 18:20:32.089 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ModelAttribute_demo_war_exploded] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Comment: Where is your error log?

Comment: Thank you.I add my error log.

Comment: Could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521730/the-absolute-uri-http-www-springsource-org-tags-form-cannot-be-resolved-in-ei

Comment: At the beginning of my address.jsp, I've the following line :

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springsource.org/tags/form" %>

Comment: When u remove the model attribute does the page render or u still get the same error?

Comment: If I do  a small change in student-form.jsp to become:  <form action="processForm" method="GET">  ,it will not have HTTP Status 500 .