# The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, tomcat, web

In Eclipse,I can't use "run as" function to open a dynamic web project. 
Error Message:"The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

However, when I export the project to a war file and deploy it, I can access the webpage.

The way I use the war file:

1. export the war file in webapps folder
2. click startup.bat
3. use browser to visit the page : localhost:8080/****

My framework:
spring4.1
tomcat8.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The absolute uri: http://www.springsource.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521730/the-absolute-uri-http-www-springsource-org-tags-form-cannot-be-resolved-in-ei)

Comment: I solved this problem by updating my tomcat from8.5 to 9.0.